# How can I create a windows service from an exe created using Go?

Tags: windows, go

I have a Go program where I am executing a command to run wmi exporter.
I have created an exe from this script using "go build".
exe works fine. 
Now, I want to create a windows service for this exe.

I have tried sc.exe, I can see the service name in the service.misc but it throws an error if I try to start it.

Comment: There is a library for creating windows service at `golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc`. An example can be found at https://github.com/golang/sys/tree/master/windows/svc/example

Comment: What error do you see? Please edit the question accordingly.

Comment: When one says "…throws an error", the only fact which can be drawn from such a definition is that "there is a problem".

Answer (score 1):

To get arbitrary EXEs to run as a Windows Service, I've had good results using [nssm](https://nssm.cc/)